# How does Oracle VARRAY represent data in Java terms?

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, varray

Slightly broad question here, but here goes

I'm trying to call an Oracle stored procedure, which returns a VARRAY which is of constructed from a ROWTYPE on one of my tables. For simplicity, lets say this table looks like the following :

```
MY_TABLE
ID   VALUE
-----------
1    John
2    Dave
```

so I will call a SP that returns the following VARRAY type :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE param_array is VARRAY(100) OF MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
```

According to the [Oracle Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/jdbc/varray/index.html), you can extract this as an array, but my question is : **what will the type of the array be, is it an array of Strings, name/value paired strings etc?**

I'm creating some Java code that will take data out of this array, but I'm not sure which format it will be, such as `1`, `John` OR `1=John` or `1,John`

Any ideas?

Comment: How would you know that `1` is the Id for `John`?

Comment: varrays start their  index at 1

Comment: it will be an array of strings, first element (0) in java (1) in plsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

```
SQL>CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMPARRAY is VARRAY(20) OF VARCHAR2(30)
SQL>/
```

Then create the following function that returns a VARRAY.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getEmpArray RETURN EMPARRAY
AS
  l_data EmpArray := EmpArray();
  CURSOR c_emp IS SELECT ename FROM EMP;
  BEGIN
    FOR emp_rec IN c_emp LOOP
      l_data.extend;
      l_data(l_data.count) := emp_rec.ename;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN l_data;
  END;
```

It will return an array of strings (VARCHARs) max length 30
it returns emparray which is declared as a varray of varchars (strings)